# Batch download of contact address records via REST?

Tags: rest, acumatica, erp

Using Acumatica ERP 2018R (V18.112.0019) which is the latest version as of this question.

I've been trying to find a way to download contact address records in batch -- not one at a time, and it seems that everything I try, I get an error from the optimizer about a BQL delegate.

I've tried using the `Default/17.200.001` endpoint to go after the `Contact` entity and use the `$expand=Address` parameter.

Often suggested as a workaround is to create a Generic Inquiry, so I've also tried extending the endpoint and get the results from a GI, but no matter how basic I make that GI, I get the same BQL delegate error.  For the DAC, I've tried using `PX.Objects.CR.Address`, `PX.Objects.CR.ContactExtAddress`, `PX.Objects.AR.ARAddress`, and went so far as to return just the `AddressID` field.  No other tables, relations, parameters, conditions, etc.  Just a very basic GI to try and get to an address.  Even if the GI worked, there's issues with being able to page the results (I get a method not allowed error when trying to do a Put to a GI, but that could just be me doing it wrong).

Looking that differences between the old endpoint Contract versions, it looks like V1 was more forgiving with sub-optimal queries than V3?  Maybe the REST API needs to have a URL parameter or a way to specify to allow a non-optimized query to run?  Or if it has that feature, I can't seem to locate it.

Any insight or examples that anyone could add would be greatly appreciated.  I can't imagine having to download contacts and/or contact address records one at a time - that would be a ridiculous number of round trips/requests and would be much slower and more of a resource hog than a single non-optimized query.

Answer (score 3):

I think I was able to solve my own problem by expanding the Contacts in the following manner:

```
Customer?$expand=ShippingContact/Address,MainContact/Address,Contacts,Contacts/Contact/Address
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do `PUT` to a Generic Inquiry entity, and in that way you should not get a delegate-related optimization error.

Comment: Can you post or link to an example.  The closest I can find in the online help is for an Inquiry Form, and doesn't seem to work for a Generic Inquiry:
[link](https://help.acumatica.com/(W(2))/main.aspx?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=6340cff3-4732-4231-9e42-5d1e5e65b5dd)

Comment: The link you're looking at is exactly the one you need, and this approach works with GI. If it doesn't it usually means you have incorrectly mapped the GI.

Comment: When I do a `PUT` to a GI, I'm only getting a single record.  I get an error when I try to add `$expand=Results`.  I'm currently trying to download CustomerLocation records, but the Default endpoint doesn't return any records.  My GI is returning records, but one at a time via REST.

Comment: What kind of error do you get when you're trying to expand `Results`?

Comment: Entry not in dictionary, but I've since realized how to make it work.  I needed to create a `Results` property within the entity and then add all the fields at that level.  I now have a GI that appears to be working properly and returning records.  I was even able add paging of the records by using a condition on the GI and (`AddressID Greater Than [passedInValue]`), and set the GI to return 100 rows. and